# Can't access Images from downloadDestination Path in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am downloading images to a specfic folder in Iphone HomeDirectory but unable to access it as it is saving images in randomly generated names. So please help me how to access them properly in my other function.

```
 - (void)fetchURL:(NSURL *)url
{
 request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedImage%d",i1];
 NSString *path = [self.documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str1];
 NSLog(@"saved image path %@",path);
 [request1 setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"]];
  //path];
 //[request1 setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1"]];
 [request1 setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
 [request1 setDelegate:self];
 [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(URLFetchWithProgressComplete:)];
 [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(URLFetchWithProgressFailed:)];
 [request1 setDownloadDestinationPath:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToStoreCachedResponseDataForRequest:request1]];
 [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] setShouldRespectCacheControlHeaders:NO]; 
 [request1 startAsynchronous];

 i1++;

 //[request1 setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"]];
 //[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:imageProgressIndicator1];
 //[self.networkQueue addOperation:request1];
}
```

Accessing Image from other function

```
    ASIDownloadCache *cache = [[[ASIDownloadCache alloc] init] autorelease];

 //NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 self.documentsDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory();
 //[paths objectAtIndex:0];

 [cache setStoragePath:self.documentsDirectoryPath];

NSLog(@"path %@",self.documentsDirectoryPath);

  self.destinationPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Library/Caches/ASIHTTPRequestCache/SessionStore"];

  //NSString *PathStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedImage%d",i];
  //NSString *appFile = [self.destinationPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:PathStr];

  //NSString *path = [self.documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:PathStr];
  //NSLog(@"images path %@",path);

  NSLog(@"Download Destination Path %@",[request1 downloadDestinationPath]);
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[request1 downloadDestinationPath]];
         //self.destinationPath];
         //[request1 downloadDestinationPath]];

  NSLog(@"Image %@ and %d",imageView.image,i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have two calls to `setDownloadDestinationPath`.  The first one sets the path to a subdirectory of your home directory, but the second one then changes it (as described in the cache part of the [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)).  You can save to either place, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the download path twice?

```
 [request1 setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"]];
  ...
 [request1 setDownloadDestinationPath:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToStoreCachedResponseDataForRequest:request1]];
```

And why are you setting the request to download to the cache? You should only have one downloadDestinationPath.

Comment: I tried to comment one request but still cant access the images stored in downloadDestinationPath as they are saving with different name and also with some HTML files, dont know where are they comming from.